# Z-index слоев

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите, в чем ошибка слоев

```
http://svitlo.me/new/index.php?route=product/category&path=70
```

Если нажать на обратный звонок (правый вверх ссылка), то не перекрываются слои фильтра.

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос... чем должны перекрываться?

поставьте id column-left  

z-index: 0; 

а то у вас стоит 99

Comment: неправильно выразился, если нажать на обратный звонок, то блок с id overlay не перекрывает слои фильтра

Comment: больше Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Как написал [[@Andrey Perov](/users/23468/andrey-perov)](/users/23468/andrey-perov):
поставьте id column-left

```
z-index: 0;
```